# $window.scroll(showScroll()) not working but onscoll="showScroll()" is?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I looked at other threads, and their mistakes had to do with typos, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.
I don't see the scroll button at all. It works when I call the function showScroll() from the body of my html using `<body onscroll="showScrol()">` but that doesn't work in IE so I'm trying to use this function but it's not working:

```
// SCROLL TO TOP
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(showScroll());

  function showScroll() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
      $("#top-btn").show();
    } else {
      $("#top-btn").hide();
    }
  }

  function scrollToTop() { 
    $(window).scrollTop(0); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Try `$(window).scroll(showScroll);` instead of `$(window).scroll(showScroll());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(window).scroll(showScroll());` means you're executing the function instantly and the return value is being passed into the scroll event.

Instead make it  `$(window).scroll(showScroll);` so it's the function that is passed in.

I created an example for you to illustrate. I guessed the html a bit but you get the point. Start scrolling the below example and see the div appear and disappear.

```js
// SCROLL TO TOP
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(showScroll); // <-- this was changed

  function showScroll() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
      $("#top-btn").show();
    } else {
      $("#top-btn").hide();
    }
  }

  function scrollToTop() { 
    $(window).scrollTop(0); 
  }
  
  const button = document.querySelector('button'); // <-- added this for completeness
  button.addEventListener('click', scrollToTop);
});
```

```css
main {
  height: 600px;
}

#top-btn {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main>
  <button id="top-btn">Show me</button>
</main>
```